# Krusader Configuration for SCP

Tags: scp, sftp, sshfs, fish-protocol

A remote router is accessible via SSH: 16.04 `scp` copies files back and forth from the command line.

```
ASUSWRT-Merlin RT-AC68U 384.7-2 Sun Oct 21 17:18:03 UTC 2018

USER@router:/tmp/home/root#   
# uname -a

Linux RT-AC68U-3D90 2.6.36.4brcmarm #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Oct 21 13:27:49 EDT 2018 armv7l ASUSWRT-Merlin
```

sftp does not seem to work from the command line:

```
sftp user@monkeybusiness.com

user@monkeybusiness.com's password: 
sh: /opt/libexec/sftp-server: not found
Connection closed
```

I would like to use a GUI (Filezilla, Krusader, Nautilus), however I have not yet met with success with this trio.

This [article indicates Krusader's fish protocol supports SCP](https://chi3x10.wordpress.com/2008/02/24/krusader-linux-ftpsftpscp-gui/), however the error received is:

```
Error: The directory ... does not exist:
```

[image]

## QUESTION

What else can be done configure Krusader to access the router and SCP (not SFTP) files?

Comment: To use sftp, both sides have to support it. The error you are seeing suggests that monkeybusiness.com is either configured incorrectly (the sshd configuration for the sftp subsystem points to the wrong location), or sftp is disabled (the sftp server has been removed). sftp is not an intrinsic part of the SSH protocol; it is implemented with an external binary as a general rule.

Comment: I honestly doubt it is on topic here whether a particular proprietary router model supports this or that protocol.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open file from remote computer on host computer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184965/open-file-from-remote-computer-on-host-computer); not an exact dupe, but the solution is the same (`sshfs`).

Answer (score 0):

## To install Optware on your RT-AC68U in three simple steps:

- Mount the ext4 formatted disk;
- Go to router’s web interface (router.asus.com) -> USB Application and install Download Master;
- Once successfully installed, uninstall it (not disable). The Optware package will remain installed, but just the Download Master will be removed.

Uninstall the Download Master because it is incompatible with transmission for Optware, a better alternative for the torrent client.

## After Optware install, install SSH server:

```
ipkg install openssh-sftp-server
```

sshfs is now possible